# Compose a URL and call it after INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Necesito crear tun disparador que llame a una URL de GAS `POST` o `GET` es indiferente parametrizada tras el evento `INSER`.

Estoy trabajando con phpMyAdmin (5.1.1) y MariaDB (10.1.48)

Estructura DB

```
Id | Parameter 1 | Parameter 2 | Parameter 3
1 | AAA | BBB  | CCC
```

Url a la que hay que llamas despues de `INSERT`

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXX/exec?parameter1=AAA&parameter2=BBBparameter3=CCC
```

He intentado

```
SET @A = NEW.A;
SET @B = NEW.B;
SET @A = NEW.C;
SET @C = NEW.D;
SELECT http_get(CONCAT ('https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec?A=',@A,'&B=',@B,'&C=',@C))
```

Con el siguiente error

```
Falló la siguiente consulta: "CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost` TRIGGER `aaaa` AFTER INSERT ON `senecadocs_mt_short_link_clicks` FOR EACH ROW SET @A = NEW.A; SET @B = NEW.B; SET @A = NEW.C; SET @C = NEW.D;"
```

MySQL ha dicho: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'SET @B = NEW.B; SET @A = NEW.C; SET @C = NEW.D' en la linea 2

Alguna idea o ejemplo que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Es necesario ver el código completo del TRIGGER.